# Where can i find a sample showing an Occasionally Connected Application in NET?

Tags: c#, .net, occasionallyconnected

Where can i find a sample showing an Occasionally Connected Application in NET?
Preferably in C# and SQL CE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [video on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb821250.aspx), with code to download.

But you state "Preferably with SQL CE", I think you always have CE client-side but that it is not (yet) supported for the server-side. They are adding some nice stuff to SQL CE 4  though.